# jQuery / JS - IE Error - Object doesn't support property or method 'hasClass'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting this error in IE 11 but no other browsers, seems like simple code but maybe I am missing something?  Below is a sample of the code.  Note I can replace parent. with the selector and it works fine.

```
$('.hs-search input[type="submit"]').click(function(){

    parent = $('.header-search');

    if(parent.hasClass('active')){
        return true;
    }else{
        parent.addClass('active');
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here is a sample of the garbage markup being generated.

```
<div class="header-search">
    <div class="hs-search">
        <div id="ctl00_header1_SearchInput1_pnlSearch" class="searchpanel " onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_header1_SearchInput1_btnSearch')" style="display:inline;">
            <input onfocus="javascript:watermarkEnter(this, 'Search');" onblur="javascript:watermarkLeave(this, 'Search');" name="ctl00$header1$SearchInput1$txtSearch" type="text" id="ctl00_header1_SearchInput1_txtSearch" title="Site Search" class=" " style="display: none;">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$header1$SearchInput1$btnSearch" value="search" id="ctl00_header1_SearchInput1_btnSearch">
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: can u share the html or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please specify WHICH ie version to accurately debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

```
parent = $('.header-search');
```

'parent' actually refers to the Window object because it bubbles up to the global scope.

Define it this way:

```
var parent = $('.header-search');
```

and it is then confined to the local scope and should work as you expect it to.

Comment: haha of course it was something stupid I over looked!  thank you!